# How to turn a matrix into a usable table using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on converting a matrix into a usable table but couldn't come up with a creative way by using SQL and basically restructuring the entire file

Any help/recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

BEFORE

```
     A       B       C       D
1   .5      .6      .7      .8      
2   .9      1.0     1.1     1.2
3   1.3     1.4     1.5     1.6
4   1.7     1.8     1.9     2.0
```

AFTER

```
X       Y       Result
A       1       .5
A       2       .9
A       3       1.3
A       4       1.7
.....
```

Comment: You  might have forgotten to give a name to the first column in your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, the simplest method is probably `union all`:

```
select 'A' as x, col1 as y, A as result from t union all
select 'B' as x, col1 as y, B as result from t union all
select 'C' as x, col1 as y, C as result from t union all
select 'D' as x, col1 as y, D as result from t;
```